# How to make Bootstrap 4 use entire width of the screen?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 with this viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Everything scales quite well expect for my monitor which allows 1920px horizontally. I put a `section` element with a border so I see how far it extends horizontally. It basically is limited to about 1100px. Adding a few px for margin, padding, etc... this limit will not be exactly at 1100px but in that neighborhood.

I am not setting `width` anywhere, myself.

Is there something in Bootstrap 4 that wants to limit horizontal scale to roughly 1100px? If so, is there a way to change this?

Comment: What does your Bootstrap markup look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap provides a class to wrap all your content depending on how you want space to be used.

You can read more about this class [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#containers)

From the same page:

> Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.

The class `container` will set a max width to your content and will center everything; the class `container-fluid` will make use of the full width of the viewport instead, look at the example in full screen.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container-fluid {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">Container</div>
<div class="container-fluid">Container Fluid</div>
```

Comment: I switched to container-fluid and everything works fine. Thanks.